# In Visual Studio how do I avoid spurious Intellisense warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I have the latest build of VS 2019 on Windows 10. I am writing two DLLs in standard C++ (not .Net).

DLL #1 calls a function in DLL #2. I included the .lib file of DLL #2 in DLL #1.

The code compiles fine and the function call works perfectly at runtime. My issue is that green squiggles appear under the function name with the message: Function definition for 'RunJaguar' not found.

DWORD RunJaguar(EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK* pECB);

Comment: I have noticed that Intellisense do not always pick declarations that are include only through precompiled headers. Thus, if it is your case, try to explicitly include the file that declare `RunJaguar`.

Other things to check might be macros or conditional compilation (`#ifdef` etc). Intellisense is less powerful or correct than the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

My psychic powers suggest you should declare your DLL functions with "extern" to make Intellisense happy:

```
extern DWORD RunJaguar(EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK* pECB);
```

Or more appropriately, use `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)` for DLL exports and imports.

Comment: That didn't work. I guess I'll just have to ignore it. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [warning pragma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=vs-2019) to avoid spurious Intellisense warning.

```
#pragma warning( push,n )//Specify the compilation warning level as Level n
//Your code
//...
#pragma warning( pop )//Restore the previous compilation warning level
```

Here is the level:

```
Warning  
Level    Meaning
-------- -------------------------------------------
     0   Turns off emission of all warning messages.

     1   Displays severe warning messages

     2   Displays level 1 warnings plus certain, less-severe warnings, such
         as warnings about hiding class members

     3   Displays level 2 warnings plus certain, less-severe warnings, such 
         as warnings about expressions that always evaluate to true or false

     4   (the default) Displays all level 3 warnings plus informational warnings
```